# React to cancellation on google play

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to react to a cancellation a user performed after a purchase on google play?
Is there anything like an event one could listen to?
Background: When using my app, the user creates an account on a server. After cancellation that account is obsolete and I'd like to remove it (e.g. with an HTTP request)

Is that possible? The mails google sends don't contain any information to identify the buyer (with good reason, I guess)

Comment: Actually, if you are talking about purchasing a paid app, and not free app downloaders, the `buyers` email address is included in the payment transaction. How you can pull that in your app remains to be seen of course (I doubt it can though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the Google Checkout Merchant API (US/UK only), you can query that for order status and take appropriate action on your server. There is no universal, Android-specific API though.